# Calculus - Rolle question

Tags: calculus, rolles-theorem

Regarding:

Let $a_{1},a_{2},a_{3},b_{1},b_{2},b_{3} \in \mathbb{R}$, while $a_{1},a_{2},a_{3}>0$ and $b_{1}<b_{2}<b_{3}$.

Prove that the equation $$\frac{a_{1}}{x-b_{1}}+\frac{a_{2}}{x-b_{2}}+\frac{a_{3}}{x-b_{3}}=0$$

has exactly two distinct solutions in $\mathbb{R}$.

--

So I have tried defining a function $f$ which is equal to the left side of the equation, derivate it, and assume by contradiction that it has more than 2 solution.

Unfortunately with no luck...

**If someone knows a way, please only give me a hint so I can solve it by myself.**

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Maybe multiplying by $(x-b_1)(x-b_2)(x-b_3)$ will help.

Comment: If you don’t have to use Rolle’s theorem, try intermediate value theorem instead.

Comment: So $f$ is continuous on $(b_{1},b_{2})$, so it also continuous on $[\frac{2b_{1}+b_{2}}{3},\frac{b_{1}+2b_{2}}{3}]$ and than use IVT ?

Comment: Also answered here: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/614063/42969

Comment: @MartinR And also here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3986096/question-regarding-lagrange-rolle-theorems

Answer (score 0):

More generally,
suppose there are $n$
$a_k$ and $b_k$ with
$a_k>0$ and
$0 < b_k < b_{k+1}$
for all $k$.

Let
$f(x)
=\sum_{k=1}^n a_k/(x-b_k)
$.

$f'(x)
=-\sum_{k=1}^n a_k/(x-b_k)^2
\lt 0
$
so $f(x)$ is always decreasing
wherever it is defined.

If $x=b_k+c$
where $c$ is small,
$f(x)>0$
because all the other terms are bounded.
Similarly,
if $x=b_k-c$
where $c$ is small,
$f(x)<0$.

This can be made rigorous by choosing
$c_0= \min(b_{k+1}-b_k)/2$,
getting an upper bound on each
$a_j/(x-b_j)$
for $|x-b_j|<c_0$
with $j\ne k$,
and making
$x-b_k$ small enough.

Therefore there is exactly one root between each pair
of $b_k$.

If $x$ is greater than all the $b_k$,
then all the terms are positive so there is no root there.

If $x$ is smaller than all the $b_k$,
then all the terms are negative so there is no root there.

Therefore the only roots are between
the $b_k$
so there are $n-1$ of them.

Comment: That is very interesting! Thanks for sharing that!

Answer (score 0):

We can simplify this equation as:
$f(x)=a_1(x-b_2)(x-b_3)+a_2(x-b_1)(x-b_3)+a_3(x-b_1)(x-b_2)$
$f(b_1)=a_1(b_1-b_2)(b_1-b_3)>0,$
$f(b_2)=a_2(b_2-b_1)(b_2-b_3)<0$
$f(b_3)=a_3(b_3-b_1)(b_3-b_2)>0.$
So by IVT, there is one root in $(b_1,b_2)$ and other one is in $(b_2,b_3)$. So only two real root of this equation which is a quadratic.

Comment: Yep, that is exact what I finally did! I also said that $f$ is monotone on each interval, so it must have only one point that $f(x)=0$, is there a theorem that I can base on to say it?

Comment: Because of discontinuities of the original function, calculus should better not be used.